# Как "согнуть" SeekBar?

Tags: android

Есть стандартный `SeekBar`, при помощи чего его можно "согнуть" под углом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам `SeekBar`

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/dot"
        android:thumb="@drawable/sun" />
```

Comment: Вам должен помочь Бендер.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется стандартным компонентом не получится. Используйте для этого лучше библиотеку [SeekArc](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc). Иконку Солнца как нибудь кастомизируете. А для получения полукруга поиграйтесь с `seekarc:startAngle и seekarc:sweepAngle`.

Думаю получите полукруг таким образом:

```
seekarc:startAngle="90"
seekarc:sweepAngle="270"
```

Comment: В ней есть один недостаток, прогресс можно кастомизировать лишь цветом, пунктир туда никак не добавить

Comment: @Heaven, тогда надо скопировать класс себе и установить пунктир в методе `onDraw()`

Comment: @Heaven, попробовали изменить с методом setThumbDrawable?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете взять код из библиотеки [SeekArc](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc) и минимально модифицировать его для вашего случая. Библиотека идёт под лицензией MIT, что фактически разрешает Вам делать с кодом что угодно.

В файле [SeekArc.java](https://github.com/neild001/SeekArc/blob/master/SeekArc_library/src/com/triggertrap/seekarc/SeekArc.java) есть метод `onDraw`, который, собственно, и делает всю магию:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
    if(!mClockwise) {
        canvas.scale(-1, 1, mArcRect.centerX(), mArcRect.centerY() );
    }

    // Draw the arcs
    final int arcStart = mStartAngle + mAngleOffset + mRotation;
    final int arcSweep = mSweepAngle;
    canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, arcStart, arcSweep, false, mArcPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, arcStart, mProgressSweep, false,
            mProgressPaint);

    if(mEnabled) {
        // Draw the thumb nail
        canvas.translate(mTranslateX - mThumbXPos, mTranslateY - mThumbYPos);
        mThumb.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

В качестве `mThumb` установите `drawable` вашего солнышка.

`mArcPaint` -- это как раз то, что вам нужно поменять используя метод `setPathEffect`. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529107/3100967) есть пример, где используются пунктирные линии для прямой и произвольной ломаной (более чистый пример создания объекта `Paint` есть также [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104138/3100967)).

В данном случае Вы так же можете применить `DashPathEffect` к объекту `mArcPaint` для рисования кривой методом `drawArc`. Вероятно, Вам так же потребуется удалить строку, которая рисует прогресс:

```
 canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, arcStart, mProgressSweep, false, mProgressPaint);
```

Просто добавьте файл в Ваш проект и внесите нужные изменения.

Answer (score 1):

Привет. Если вы хотите создать такой SeekBar (звезда + орбита) то у вас ничего не выйдет. Вам нужно создавать кастомный элемент и на нем самостоятельно менять местоположение звезды в зависимости от значений.

Comment: Зачем их создавать если они уже есть, надо только подменить тхамб звездой и бэкграунд пунктиром

Comment: тогда просто получится косая линия, но в любом случаи это не будет дугой

Comment: Дуга полукруг...

Comment: используя несколько тригонометрических формул, можно будет точно определить местоположение спутника, так чтобы его центр стоял на дуге
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8X6tTe_EasFSjQzY0t3Z0ZfSW8/view?usp=sharing]